# C# UWP XAML create ellipse with gradient

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-universal

How is it possible to create an ellipse with gradient borders, which contains a "cropped" image? Currently i only have the ellipse with the image inside

```
<Ellipse Height="300" Width="300">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="imageBrush" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Now i need to make the border transition from the image to go to transparent. Is that possible somehow in UWP XAML?

Here is an example image, which is somewhat to what i try to achieve

[image]

Comment: Can you insert your intended result? (from photoshop or something..)

Comment: I've added a demo image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[RadialGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.RadialGradientBrush?view=winui-2.4) from winui.

> Install-Package Microsoft.UI.Xaml

```xml
 xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media"

 ...

   <Grid>
        <Image Source="/Assets/m.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <Rectangle >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <media:RadialGradientBrush 
                Center="0.5,0.5"
                GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                Opacity="1"
                RadiusX="0.5"
                RadiusY="0.5"
                SpreadMethod="Pad">
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.6" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
                </media:RadialGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: One thing to note, i get this warning message: 'RadialGradientBrush' is deprecated: Please migrate to the RadialGradientBrush control from WinUI, this control will be removed in a future release.

Comment: Oh yes. It was moved from toolkit to winui. See updated answer.